# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value in scrapy

Tags: json, scrapy

I am using scrapy
json.load(response.body)

and we found JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Here is the link 
https://www.magellanprovider.com/ProviderSearchGateway/sessions/52229928/providers.jsonp?start=1&end=100&callback=jQuery112404923709263392255_1547626291787&_=1547626291795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have JS callback in your response. Try to remove extra variables from your url like `https://www.magellanprovider.com/ProviderSearchGateway/sessions/52229928/providers.jsonp?start=1&end=100` or use regex to cut json from response text.

Answer (score 1):

if you haven't notice your text starts from `jQuery112404923709263392255_1547626291787` due to this line, string can't be converted to `json`

Try using this simple `regex` to get the `json` string and then parse it to `json.loads()`

```
r'\(({.*)\);'    #it caputures anything starts from `{` and ends with `);`
```